# How can I compare elements of two one-dimensional arrays with equal sets of elements according their order?

Tags: arrays, c, for-loop, if-statement, comparison

I am trying to compare elements of two arrays according their order
for example:

```
int a[] = { 1, 2, 3 };
int b[] = { 1, 2, 4 };
```

Having 3 elements there is no problem with a `for`-loop and condition

```
if (a[0] == b[0] && a[1] == b[1] && a[2] == b[2])
```

But how can I do the same with n elements in arrays?
The condition should looks like: `if (a[0] == b[0] && a[1] == b[1] && a[2] == b[2] && ... && a[n] == b[n])` but it's inappropriate.

```
// Comparing elements of two one-dimensional arrays with
// equal sets of elements according their order.

#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    // two one-dimensional arrays with 3 elements for example
    int a[] = { 1, 2, 3 };
    int b[] = { 1, 2, 4 };

    // comparing elements:

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        if (a[0] == b[0] && a[1] == b[1] && a[2] == b[2]) // but if I have n - elements the problem appears
        {
            printf("all right\n");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("no all right\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having both a `for` loop and an explicit comparison expression is redundant.  You can solve the problem for an arbitrary number of elements with a simple function that takes both arrays and their length, compares the array elements and returns a boolean value:

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>

bool compare_arrays(const int *a, const int *b, size_t n) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (a[i] != b[i])
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}

int main() {
    // two one-dimensional arrays with 3 elements for example
    int a[] = { 1, 2, 3 };
    int b[] = { 1, 2, 4 };
    size_t a_len = sizeof(a) / sizeof(*a);

    // comparing elements:
    if (compare_arrays(a, b, a_len)) {
        printf("all right\n");
    } else {
        printf("no all right\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The great thing about for loops is that the incrementing variable i can actually be used to index into your array! Notice how you are comparing every element of a to every element of b incrementing by one. Your variable i is also incrementing by one. Your code right now checks the entire array 3 complete times, making your runtime three times longer than necessary, in addition to not being scalable. Fix it by comparing a[i] to b[i]. If they are not the same, print your message and break the loop using the break keyword. If you reach the end of the loop and they are all the same, print your success message.

Answer (score 0):

This for loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    if (a[0] == b[0] && a[1] == b[1] && a[2] == b[2]) // but if I have n - elements the problem appears
    
    {
        printf("all right\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("no all right\n");
    }
}
```

does not make sense because within it all three elements of the array are compared in the if statement in each iteration of the loop.

```
    if (a[0] == b[0] && a[1] == b[1] && a[2] == b[2]) // but if I have n - elements the problem appears
```

What you need is that in each iteration of the loop to compare corresponding elements of the array with the given index `i`.

So you can write for example

```
int i = 0;
while ( i < 3 && a[i] == b[i] ) ++i;

if ( i == 3 )
{       
    printf("all right\n");
}
else
{
    printf("no all right\n");
}
```

you could form such a comparison of two arrays as a separate function as for example

```
int compare_arrays( const int a[], const int b[], size_t n )
{
    size_t i = 0;

    while ( i < n && a[i] == b[i] ) ++i;

    return i == n;
}
```

The function returns `1` if two arrays are equal each other and `0` otherwise.

So in main you can write for example

```
if ( compare_arrays( a, b, 3 ) )
{       
    printf("all right\n");
}
else
{
    printf("no all right\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> But how can I do the same with n elements in arrays? The condition should looks like: `if (a[0] == b[0] && a[1] == b[1] && a[2] == b[2] && ... && a[n] == b[n])` but it's inappropriate.

Use a loop:

```
int result = 1;
for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++)
    if (a[i] != b[i])
        break;
if (i <= n) result = 0; /* if we exited prematurely, change result into a 0 */
```

**Beware:** you used a loop to check elements from 0 to `n` (this is `n + 1` elements, and this is how the test is written in the `for` loop)  but in the text, you talk about checking arrays of `n` elements (which should range from `0` to `n-1` indices)  in that case the loop should be:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) /* pay attention to the comparison operator */
```

and the test after should be modified equally:

```
if (i < n) result = 0;
```

I comment this because it is a very common mistake to write incorrectly the test clause in a `for` statement.